# Django Authentication register API

Tags: django

I am trying to register users in django auth module through an API call but the users are getting registered without the password being hashed which, I suspect, is making my authentication fail. Registering the users through the admin form is hashing the password and therefore working.

I developed my own User model by extending AbstractBaseUser and also created a UserManager extending BaseUserManager and defining the create_user and create_superuser method. I developed a simple serializer for it.
I read somewhere that the password can only be hashed if I developed the Admin form as well and so I did it. In this form, I followed django documentation and developed clean_password and save functions. I also registered these forms on the app admin.py.
Lastly, I created the APIView to the POST requests where I send the registration json and use the serializer do validate and save.

## model

```py
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self.create_user(email,
                                password=password,
                                **extra_fields)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    photo_path = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        return self

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

## serializer

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(object):
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
```

## forms

```py
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'photo_path')

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'photo_path', 'password')

    def clean_password(self):
        return self.initial["password"]
```

## admin.py

```py
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'is_staff')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')}
         ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

## view post

```py
class CreateUserAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request):
        user = request.data
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I expected to get a user in the DB with a hashed password, like when I create a user in the admin panel. but I get a user created with a plain text password.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do, is the following in your serializer. Notice the `set_password`. That way you make sure it is hashed

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using md5 for hashing then you can use the hashlib module and hash the password before saving in `create_superuser`

```
form hashlib import md5

def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    user = self.create_user(email,password=md5(password),**extra_fields)
    user.is_admin = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

Comment: Django already comes with a set of hashers so there is no need to import that. However I just found out that what was wrong was the way i created a user with the serializer. It wasn't using any of the model methods i had created.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the quick auto-response but I found out that the view post code was actually not executing my model create_user code. I don't know what was connecting the .save() method of the serializer to the authentication system but it was still creating the users. I will leave this question open so someone can maybe explain what was happening. To make it work i did the following changes:

```
class CreateUserAPIView(APIView):
   permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

   def post(self, request):
       user = User.objects.create_user(request.data['email'], request.data['password']);
       return Response(user, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```